# maven dependency resolving problem

Tags: maven

maven is downloading every dependency when doing ' **mvn clean package**'  . along with the dependencies , its also trying to download maven-metadata.xml with each dependency. In my system maven is not able to download this maven-metadata.xml . Does anyone know , what is this maven-metadata.xml ? and the possibilities of download failure ?

Answer (score 0):

maven-metadata.xml is required only if you do not know the group id, artifact id and version information. Please post your pom.xml here. There could be some issues with it. Also, ensure your local Maven repository (on Windows, D:\Documents and Settings\user.name.m2\repository) contains the needed dependencies.

For example, log4j can be considered correctly installed locally only if the repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.12 folder contains a Jar file and POM file. When these two are present and you mention artifact id, group id and version correctly in pom.xml, Maven will pick up the jar file locally and will NOT download each time you build.

Comment: The dependency entries in my pom.xml file are as below,

Comment: <dependencies><dependency>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java
</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependencies>

Comment: Now, check if all the above dependencies are correctly installed in your local repository - check for the artifact id, group id and version. Then ensure the jar file and pom files are present for each dependency.

Comment: I copied the .m2/repository folder from my colleague machine . It works now . Actually I am setting up my dev enviroment newly after installing OS. I am not getting why it was not working for me when I started do ' build'  for the first time. As you said, maven will download the maven-metadata.xml for each artifact when we didnt provide the group-id , artifact-id , version ?